# Facebook share doesn't load picture

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to figure out why facebook refuses to load og:image from https://www.tradingfloor.com/posts/debt-laden-yingli-kicks-the-can-down-the-road-6385661

According to the facebook debugger all the tags should be ok, but the og:image is loaded as a 1x1 pixel im instead of the real one, clicking the blank space loads the correct image.

Anybody has some ideas as to what is going on?

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tradingfloor.com%2Fposts%2Fdebt-laden-yingli-kicks-the-can-down-the-road-6385661

NOTE:
I've tested in twitter, linkedin and google+ all of them loads the expected image.

Comment: Putting the image URL directly into the debug tool, it says _“Could not retrieve data from URL”_, which indicates a problem with downloading the image. If you can, try using an HTTP URL instead of an HTTPS one for your `og:image` – HTTPS for images sometimes is problematic with Facebook for whatever reason. (Right now, requesting your image via HTTP redirects to HTTPS automatically – so try to exempt images from that redirect, and then try with the HTTP URL for og:image.)

Comment: But I found a blog running HTTPs that has no problems. Doing what you describe results in the same "Could not retrieve data from url" but their image works no problem.

This is the blog I tested it with: https://syrienblog.net/2015/10/06/haifaa-awad-hylder-det-muslimske-broderskab/

Answer (score 1):

Just in case somebody else finds this. It was related to this bug, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/388405488023104/

Implementing the workaround worked fine, but facebook says they have a fix ready now.